# Converting Dataframe column to datetime doesn't complete

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert a column of a large dataset (660k rows) into datetime type in Jupyter notebook. I have found two ways to do it:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['local_time'],format='%d/%m/%Y') 
df['local_time'].astype("datetime64[ns]")
```

but none of them complete even in couple hours. Is there a way to make it faster? It doesn't look that any of the laptop's resources would be used 100%. My laptop is Acer S7. Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz. Ram 8Gb

Comment: Have you tried it on a subset of your dataframe? Try with 10, 100, 1000, 10000,..., rows - that way you can see if this is the actual problem, and what the expected time is for the whole dataframe.

Comment: Did a 1 run for 200000. #timeit sys it took 3min, although in reality it was 6 min. Could Chrome run out of memory although the system still has some unused? Maybe a problem with pyarrow?

Comment: 100 000 ran for 1min47s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was the reason behind it, but I was converting multiple columns at once and the time increased many many times.

```
df[['date_1', 'date_2', 'date_3', 'date_4']] = df[['date_1', 'date_2', 'date_3', 'date_4']].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

after doing everything in separate  steps, time became decent

```
df['date_1'] = df['date_1'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['date_2'] = df['date_2'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['date_3'] = df['date_3'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['date_4'] = df['date_4'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```